# Using/Understanding Foreign Keys

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables:

1. Project_Info table that contains the project id (primary key), project name, and the project budget.
2. Project_Forecast table that contains project name and forecast amount

My question is...should I refer to the primary key in the Project_Info table in the Project_Forecast table? I'm new to SQL so I might be misunderstanding the concept but would doing this essentially refer each forecast amount back to the project via the project ID? If not, what would be better way of leveraging the primary key/foreign keys between these two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should I refer to the primary key in the Project_Info table in the Project_Forecast table?

Yes

> so I might be misunderstanding the concept but would doing this essentially refer each forecast amount back to the project via the project ID?

That's correct

Here is a basic schema for the tables you described:

```
CREATE TABLE project_info (
    id serial unique, -- project ID
    name text,
    budget int
);

CREATE TABLE project_forecast  (
    id serial unique,
    project_id int REFERENCES project_info (id),
    forecast_budget int
);
```

Comment: Thank you! How will the Project_Forecast table refer back to the project ID? I understand it's through the foreign key but in terms of populating the table, how does it do it?

Comment: It will behave just like a nomal table without a foreign key. But when you add rows to `project_forecast` they will have to have a matching row in `project_info` for the `project_id` if not you will have an error.

Comment: If my answer fits your needs I would appreciate if you could select it as the correct answer for your question!

Comment: Is it considered a match if the project name from the Project Forecast table matches with the project ID from the Project Info table?

Comment: No, the ID from `project_info` has to match `project_id` in `project_forecast`, not the names. By the way if the names are the same, no need to store it into `project_forecast` as well

Comment: Yes, the names are the same, which is why I just wanted to use the foreign keys to refer to the project names.

Comment: So the column name is not needed in `project_forecast`, I will update my answer

Comment: One more question, is "id serial"  in both the tables referring to the same primary key?

Comment: `id serial` will be the primary key for each table. It will increment by one for each new row.

Comment: Can you declare multiple data types with the same variable names?

Answer (score 0):

you should build your tables like this,

```
Project_Info(
 PojectID PK,
 ProjectName,
 ProjectBudget
)

Poject_Forecast(
ForcastID PK,
ProjectID FK,
ForcastAmount
)
```

The reason you don't want to have project name in the forecast table is that it is a property of a project and it would be redundant (non-normalized) to have it in two tables and cumbersome to manage if the project name changes. But to answer your question having the FK would relate each forecast to a project and would also not allow forecasts be created for projects that don't exist, or projects with forecasts be deleted. In other words when you make foreign keys the database will enforce referential integrity.

also I'm sure some people will mention if I don't you don't absolutely need a ForcastID  in the ProjectForecast Table but it is probably a good idea.

I hope this answers your question.